# Javafx2 modify button when clicked

Tags: java, button, javafx, event-listener

Im trying to make it so when a button is clicked, I can change one of its properties.

```
class Tile extends Button{
  public int position[];
  public Tile(){
    super();
    position = 0;
  }

 }
```

Where initialized:

```
{
  Tile tiles [][] = new Tile[10][10];
  for(int i=0; i<10; i ++){
    for(int j =0; j<10; j++){
      tiles[i][j].position = i*10+j;
      tiles[i][j].addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println(((Tile)(e.getSource())).position[1]); //this results in a null pointer
                }
            });
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like the program to print out the position value in the tile when it is clicked. Is there any way to access the object which the event is referring to?
I really just need to know which tile in the array was clicked. 
edit:
When I try to use e.getSource(), i get a NullPointerException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position is declared an an Array, yet you use it an a Int.

Changing it to a simple int should fix your problem.

```
class Tile extends Button{
  public int position;
  public Tile(){
    super();
    position = 0;
  }

 }
```

The Initialization method:

```
{
  Tile tiles [][] = new Tile[10][10];
  for(int i=0; i<10; i ++){
    for(int j =0; j<10; j++){
      tiles[i][j].position = i*10+j;
      tiles[i][j].addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println(((Tile)(e.getSource())).position);
                }
            });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it keeps give me a null pointer.  I've edited the question to reflect what I used.

Comment: You declared position as an Array of int but you're assigning it a int. Hence the null pointer.

Comment: Whups, it was actually because I never initialized the array. I've got it working now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

As stated by the user PeekaySwitch, you can get the source of the event triggered by the button, in which case it is the button. All you must do is apply a cast to get you the correct type of the desired object:

```
@Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) 
{
    Button button = (Button) e.getSource();
}
```

After doing this, you just need to get the object properties and handles them the way you want. Do not forget that the [types of events](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/event/ActionEvent.html) in JavaFX are all part of the [Java standard library](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html).

With respect to its exception null value, you are making a basic mistake of language. The next code snippet you start the reference to the array of objects:

```
Tile tiles [][] = new Tile[10][10];
```

However, you are not starting the objects within the vector. Try to start each Tile object by doing the following:

```
tiles[i][j] = new Tile();
```

Place this code inside of nested loops, and before each Tile object being used.

Hope this helps you. Good luck.

Comment: Also valid corrections to the code I posted (which had several mistakes due to typing on an ipad from memory).  Thanks for the help, I've got it figured out.